# Error when trying to push Lightning EmailTemplates SFDX

Tags: email, salesforcedx, email-template

I'm trying to push two email templates along with other metadata using SFDX. Here's the folder structure:

```
force-app\main\default
    applications
    email
        Demo_Email_Templates
            FirstEmail.email
            FirstEmail.email-meta.xml
            SecondEmail.email
            SecondEmail.email-meta.xml
        Demo_Email_Templates.emailFolder-meta.xml
    flexipages
```

When I try to push my metadata with the Demo_Email_Templates folder I receive the following error:

> Error  N/A           To store the email template in the public folder,
> enter the Salesforce organization ID. To store it in a user’s private
> folder, enter t that user’s ID.
>
> Error  N/A           Custom Object Definition ID: bad value for
> restricted picklist field: My_Object__c'

**Demo_Email_Templates.emailFolder-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmailFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <accessType>Public</accessType>
    <name>Demo Email Templates</name>
    <publicFolderAccess>ReadWrite</publicFolderAccess>
</EmailFolder>
```

**Meta XML for My_Object__c**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmailTemplate xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <available>true</available>
    <description>some description</description>
    <encodingKey>ISO-8859-1</encodingKey>
    <name>Notify People</name>
    <relatedEntityType>My_Object__c</relatedEntityType>
    <style>none</style>
    <subject>Revisions are requested on your Concept Note</subject>
    <type>custom</type>
    <uiType>SFX</uiType>
</EmailTemplate>
```

**Email Template for My_Object__c**

```
<html>
 <head> 
  <title></title> 
 </head> 
 <body style="height: auto; min-height: auto;">
  Dear {{{Recipient.Name}}}, 
  <br /> 
  <br /> Dummy Text XYZ {{{My_Object__c.Name}}}. //I tried removing this line as well
  <br /> 
  <br /> Regards, 
  <br /> {{{Sender.Name}}} 
  <ul> 
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Do I need to add a setting in the dx JSON definition file? What else am I missing?

**Edit:** These Email Templates will be packaged (managed package).

Comment: How you're triggering mails?

Comment: The templates are going in a package, users can choose to fire them how they like. @YsrShk

Comment: Yeah I have unlocked package and its created in package.

Comment: I did not see where is the lightning is mentioned in your configuration. I am having email template in unlocked package.

Comment: It's a managed package

Comment: oh okay.  May be for Managed one, its not provided then.

Answer (score 1):

i also faced same issue. when ever  your `EmailTemplate`'s exist in your custom folder, you need add that folder Developer name also in you package.xml.

in my case `test for me` as my custom folder, type is `Email`.

[image]

**Package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
 <types>
 <members>test_for_me</members>
 <members>test_for_me/contact_response_Confirmation</members>
 <name>EmailTemplate</name>
</types>
  <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

**command:**

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -x ./manifest/package.xml -u mytargetorg
```

Comment: I'm not deploying using `deploy` command I'm just doing a normal `push`. How would using a manifest help?  Or is this only way to push Email Templates to an org?

Comment: i believe your using scratch org, yes you can use `push` instead of  `deploy` but rest of thing same.  in your case folder is different metadata component and `emailtemplate` is different. 1) create manifest folder then  2)reate package.xml file in manifest folder then 3)add code what ever i provided  then run command

Comment: No what I meant to say is that there is no difference it's giving me the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Error N/A To store the email template in the public folder, enter the
> Salesforce organization ID. To store it in a user’s private folder,
> enter t that user’s ID.

I had similar issue, where I was doing 2 mistakes -

1. I did not have set Workflow User configuration (because I was using Email Alert from Process Builder and to send email, I was using workflow user)
2. I was sending Unified public folder.

For first issue I added below part in `project-scratch-def.json` -

```
{
  "orgName": "<Some-Org-Name",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": ["DefaultWorkflowUser"] 
}
```

For second issue, I used another folder with public access, which I can see you did it correct.

> Error N/A Custom Object Definition ID: bad value for restricted
> picklist field: My_Object__c'

This is mostly because,either there is picklist which is restricted(to store predefined values) not directly here, somewhere in the flow/related files.

Comment: The second issue is resolved when I remove the email templates so not sure if it is something else.

Comment: Tried your approach didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, Lightning Email Templates can't be packaged, more info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_emailtemplate.htm).

Comment: Here they're claiming its supported. Link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/49

Comment: Not really if you follow the link once you click on EmailTemplate it will tell you that it's not supported, it's also the link I mentioned above.

Comment: But in that line, they have sign to denote that its supported. [for managed one]